# Why is Google Forms not matching the regex with the text entered by the user?

Tags: regex, google-forms

In a short answer question in Google Forms, I have set data validation to Regular Expression with the condition of "Matches" to:

```
(MS|MP|PH)[0-9]{5}|Faculty
```

I want something like "MS18057" (etc.) or "Faculty" to be entered by the user. But in the form, I can enter "xyzFaculty" (etc.), and it seems that the condition "Matches" is behaving like "Contains."

I tried the same by removing the **|Faculty** portion and I was able to enter "MS18057" (etc.) only as the answer. So it worked fine without **|**. Why is it so?

Comment: You could try using anchors `^(?:(?:MS|MP|PH)[0-9]{5}|Faculty)$` to prevent getting a partial match. https://regex101.com/r/a5Bdc0/1

Comment: I understand that regex will match the specified text even if there are extra characters. What I don't understand is that in Google Forms "Matches"  and "Contains" are two different options and that "Matches" by default should match to the exact text?

Comment: I have never used forms before. I just created a test form and it seems that that is the case. If you want to use contains you could use word boundaries `\b(?:(?:MS|MP|PH)[0-9]{5}|Faculty)\b` https://regex101.com/r/GDDnOy/1 This [page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en) contains some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "Matches" condition and set the RegEx as `^((MS|MP|PH)[0-9]{5}|Faculty)$`

[image: Google Forms RegEx]

Comment: "Contains" with this regex also does the same job. So, how "Matches" is different from "Contains?"